# prove negative and positive everywhere for some point

Tags: real-analysis

Let

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}x+ 2x^2 \sin(1/x),& x \neq 0 \\
0,& x=0.\end{cases}$$

If I want to show $f'(0) = 1$.

$\frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h} =  1 + 2h \sin(1/h) = 1$

then How to prove that $f'(x)$ assumes both positive and negative
values in every neighborhood?

Is sin function is kind of obvious that its negative and positive value everywhere 
for every point?

Comment: First of all, compute $f'(x)$ also for $x\ne 0$ (should be more straightforward than the special case $x=0$)

Comment: hmm. i dont get it

Answer (score 0):

you must note that if $x\neq0$, you have, 
$$f'(x) = 1 - 2\cos(1/x) + 4 x \sin(1/x).$$

If we consider the limit of $f'$ when ${x\to0}$ we have problems with the cosine part.

For example, take $\alpha\in(-1,1)$, and take $x_n =\frac{1}{\alpha + \frac{\pi}{2} + 2\pi n}$.

If we take limits, we have $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = 0$. Now,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1-2\cos(\alpha+\pi/2)+4\ x_n\sin(1/x_n)\right)= 1 - 2\cos(\alpha+\pi/2).$$

If we choose $\alpha\in(0,1)$, then $\cos(\alpha + \pi/2) < 0$, and, $f'(x_n) > 0$, for large $n$,

in the other hand if we choose $\alpha\in(-1,0)$ we get that $\cos(\alpha + \pi/2) > 0$, if we choose $\alpha\in(-1,0)$ with value $\cos(\alpha + \pi/2) > 1/2$, then $f'(x_n)<0$ for a large $n$.

In any case, we can take points in every neighborhood of $0$ with $f'>0$ and take points in the same neighborhood of $0$ with $f'<0$